# Как удалить файлы с сайта из другого поддомена PHP

Tags: php

У меня **сайт** и **телеграм бот** на разных поддоменах

```
www.example.com
bot.example.com
```

Хочу реализовать механизм автоматического удаляения файлов после прошествия Энного времени

Настраиваю через CRON. Механизм такой:

Телеграм бот, смотрит по БД кто из пользователей совершил некое действие и если `true` то циклом удаляет файлы по имеющемуся списку

Только бот живет в одном поддомене, а файлы в другом.

Само удаление пытался сделать через `unlink()`

```
$photos = ["1.jpg", "2.png"]
foreach ($photos as $one_photo) {
   unlink('https://www.example.com/img/users/'.$one_photo);
}
```

**Внимание вопрос, можно ли реализовать удаление находясь в другом поддомене?**

Comment: если файлы лежат на одном сервере, то можно указывать путь без `https`, например, `../../../example.com/img/users`

Comment: Спасибо! Пока не знаю решит ли это новшество мою задачу, но попробую)

Comment: @DrMcSheen все таки помогло - спасибо!) Можете написать ответ, я отблагодарю)